# Android app that shows notification when server sending data

Tags: android, background, alarmmanager

What service should I use to check every few seconds when the app is closed, if there is any data incoming from the server?

I tried `Alarm Manager` and schedule multiple alarms that schedule each other every few seconds. But the alarm manager is not very accurate. Then I checked out `JobScheduler` , but it's good for specific conditions. Is there any service that is good for this need?